# MapView in scroll tab display nothing

Tags: android

please help.
I am trying to display a google map in a scroll tab, but I am getting a blank google map.
Since I am using the scroll tab, I use android.support.v4.app.Fragment in the PagerAdapter class and the fragment class which should display the map.

The following is fragment class to display a google map

```html
package ui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.bdushimi.bjhangout.R;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapTab extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public static View view;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapView mapView;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;


    public MapTab() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View v, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

        mapView = (MapView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mapView.onResume();
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    }
    
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40.689247, -74.044502))
                .title("You're here"));
   
    }
}
```

The following is the xml

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ui.MapTab">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to know where I am getting wrong or possibly another approach I should consider. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are using V4 all the way through? No Fragment normal anywhere or v7 adapters or anything that could cause a mismatch? Just something to double check if you hadn't already. Also, is there any difference if the MapView fragment is the first view you see in the pager instead of scrolling to it?

Comment: It makes no difference whichever you view first, still it displays a blank google map. for V4, yes, I did use them for the entire project

Comment: bummer was hoping it was something simple like that. Unfortunately to troubleshoot any further I would have to have your code and experiment with it, which is not something I have time to do, my apologies. Goodluck though, and definitely update your answer once you figure it out in case anyone else ever hits this issue.